# How do i access the windows 10 bedrock edition texture files for minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm trying to make my own texture pack for windows 10 bedrock edition but i can only find java edition files please help?

Answer (score 2):

Unlike Java edition, you can't really edit any texture pack you want by simply going into the specific folder. To edit texture packs you need to download a Zip file from [Here](https://aka.ms/resourcepacktemplate) This is from the official Minecraft Blog. Then edit the file. After you're done change extension to .mcpack after it. After that you can go about one of these steps:-

1. install simply click on it and Minecraft Bedrock will automatically install it into the game.

Comment: Current unshortened url: https://github.com/Mojang/bedrock-samples/releases

Answer (score 0):

Of course. You can access the texture pack files for Bedrock by simply going to "%localappdata%\Packages\Microsoft.MinecraftUWP_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\games\com.mojang\resource_packs" location on your PC (you can paste it into the File Explorer bar).

Comment: As of 1.20.1 (and likely earlier), this folder only contains your custom resource packs, not the default resources.